# Apache wicket - page store - error while using AsynchronousPageStore

Tags: java, serialization, wicket

I am trying to use  AsynchronousPageStore for our Application, by doing the following

First I created an asynchronous DiskPageStore

```
public class McAsynchronousDiskPageStore extends DiskPageStore
    {

        public McAsynchronousDiskPageStore()
        {
            super( PortalApp.this.getName(), PortalApp.this.getStoreSettings().getFileStoreFolder(), Bytes.kilobytes( 40000));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canBeAsynchronous(IPageContext context)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

To pass it as delegate  for an implementation of  AsynchronousPageStore

```
public class CustomPageStoreManeger extends AsynchronousPageStore
{

    private final IPageStore delegate;

    public CustomPageStoreManeger(IPageStore delegate)
    {
        super( delegate, 100);
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy()
    {

        Logger.getLogger( this).logInfo( " page store Size" + ((IPersistentPageStore)delegate).getTotalSize());

    }

    @Override
    public void addPage(IPageContext context, IManageablePage page)
    {
        if( INotPersistentPage.class.isAssignableFrom( page.getClass()))
        {
            Logger.getLogger( this).debug( " ignoring page persitence" + page.getClass());
        }
        else
        {
            super.addPage( context, page);
        }
    }
```

I'm setting it as follows in my WicketApplication class

```
    setPageManagerProvider( new DefaultPageManagerProvider( this)

    {

        @Override
        protected IPageStore newPersistentStore()

        {

            return new CustomPageStoreManeger( new McAsynchronousDiskPageStore());

        }

    });
```

yet , I get the following error in the console

```
09:31:44,699 ERROR [AsynchronousPageStore$PageAddingRunnable] (Wicket-AsyncPageStor) An error occurred while saving asynchronously 'PendingAdd [sessionId=6A4jzJpJbU8YMgb9J-_npsnLGsywu6xi0jJmkAiY, pageId=7, pageClass=org.apache.wicket.pageStore.SerializedPage]': org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: session attribute can not be changed asynchronuously
    at deployment.xx-12.0.ear//org.apache.wicket.pageStore.AsynchronousPageStore$PendingAdd.getSessionAttribute(AsynchronousPageStore.java:198)
    at deployment.xx-12.0.ear//org.apache.wicket.pageStore.AsynchronousPageStore$PendingAdd.getSessionAttribute(AsynchronousPageStore.java:201)
    at deployment.xx-12.0.ear//org.apache.wicket.pageStore.AbstractPersistentPageStore.getSessionIdentifier(AbstractPersistentPageStore.java:149)
    at deployment.xx-12.0.ear//org.apache.wicket.pageStore.AbstractPersistentPageStore.canBeAsynchronous(AbstractPersistentPageStore.java:76)
    at deployment.xx-12.0.ear//org.apache.wicket.pageStore.AsynchronousPageStore.addPage(AsynchronousPageStore.java:369)
    at deployment.xx-12.0.ear.web.war/xxx.PortalApp$CustomPageStoreManeger.addPage(PortalApp.java:206)
    at deployment.xx-12.0.ear//org.apache.wicket.pageStore.AsynchronousPageStore$PageAddingRunnable.run(AsynchronousPageStore.java:292
```

any idea what I  might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO there is no need of `McAsynchronousDiskPageStore`.

Instead of overriding `#newPersistentStore()` in `DefaultPageManagerProvider` you should override `protected IPageStore newAsynchronousStore(IPageStore pageStore)` and return `McAsynchronousDiskPageStore` without any delegates.

https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/0c4b88e16a3ec7478fbc8f86991c6b07805ed821/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/DefaultPageManagerProvider.java#L158